# Click all values in a drop down list using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm scrapping a website

> http://tabnet.saude.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/cgi/deftohtm3.exe?secretarias/saude/TABNET/AIHRD08/AIHRDNET08.def

I need to select all values in the field `Períodos Disponíveis`.
I created a `for` loop to do it because the Xpath of field follow a sequence:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="A"]')
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    for option in all_options:
        option.click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="A"]/option[1]').click()
```

But this is too slow, how can I make this faster?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? This isn't a multiple-choice field, so clicking each `option` just changes the focus on every iteration

Comment: There are too many answers: do not use Selenium, multi-threading your code, distributed system, ...

Comment: You want to select all values. Does it mean selecting all values holding shift?

Comment: Do you just need to collect all the options, or do you need to check that it is possible to click on all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested and I have implemented keyboard shortcut. After identifying the element:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="A"]')
```

Use send keys

```
element.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.END)
```

Assumption is that you have already declared Keys as:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: Wow, i try this but dont work. Now it's work haha, Tks